# Unpermitted parameter error - Devise + Paperclip + Heroku + S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, devise, paperclip

I could really use some help on getting a profile image to upload correctly to S3 via an application I've built using Devise for users and Paperclip for the image upload.

My other models are all working great with Paperclip thru Heroku to S3, the only model I can't get working is the User model from Devise. I've read a 100 different articles on setting up configured permitted parameters for devise and no variable seems to work.  I've read all the Stack Overflow Q&A's on this issue and none seem to relate to mine.

I added other attributes to the user model (profile name, dob, etc.) and all of those attributes are working just fine.  Only the image is not working.

I've included below the complete log file that shows the Error Message - "Unpermitted Parameter: polaroid."

Paperclip 'image' file name is called 'Polaroid'.

Any thoughts??  thanks!

Application Controller.rb

```
     class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
      # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
      # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
        protect_from_forgery with: :exception


        before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

        protected

        def configure_permitted_parameters
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update).push(:email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation, :profile_name, :profile_dob, :profile_zipcode, :profile_country, :profile_timezone, :profile_datejoined, :profile_occupation, :profile_school, :profile_biography, :filter_dateyesno, :filter_distancefrom, :filter_organizerage_min, :filter_organizerage_max, :filter_groupsize_min, :filter_groupsize_max, :profile_gender, :polaroid)
            devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up).push(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_name, :profile_dob, :profile_zipcode, :profile_country, :profile_timezone, :profile_datejoined, :profile_occupation, :profile_school, :profile_biography, :filter_dateyesno, :filter_distancefrom, :filter_organizerage_min, :filter_organizerage_max, :filter_groupsize_min, :filter_groupsize_max, :profile_gender, :polaroid)
        end


    end
```

Users Controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
        def index
            @users = User.all
        end 

        def show
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
        end 

        private
            def user_params
                params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :current_password, :password_confirmation, :profile_name, :profile_dob, :profile_zipcode, :profile_country, :profile_timezone, :profile_datejoined, :profile_occupation, :profile_school, :profile_biography, :filter_dateyesno, :filter_distancefrom, :filter_organizerage_min, :filter_organizerage_max, :filter_groupsize_min, :filter_groupsize_max, :profile_gender, :polaroid)
            end

    end
```

Edit.html.erb from Devise Registration

```
<h2>Update Profile Information</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
      <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
    <% end %>

    <% if current_user.polaroid.exists? %>
      <%= image_tag (current_user.polaroid.url(:small)) %><br/>
      <%= f.file_field :polaroid, multiple: true %>
    <% else %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :profile_photo %>
        <%= f.file_field :polaroid, multiple: true %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_name, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :birthday %><br />
      <%= f.date_field :profile_dob, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :gender %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_gender, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :zipcode %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_zipcode, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :country %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_country, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :timezone %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_timezone, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :occupation %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_occupation, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :university_attended %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_school, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :biography %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_biography, autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <br />
    <%= f.input :filter_dateyesno, label: "Are you single and looking for dates?", as: :radio_buttons %>
    <br />

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :new_password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :new_password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <br />

  <h4>Make sure to type in your password before updating</h4>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Update" %>

<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

Other Paperclip Model that is working:

```
        Started POST "/outings" for ::1 at 2016-06-25 20:47:39 -0400
    Processing by OutingsController#create as HTML

      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/eflxdhQ1vPTnTE1YnCOes0k6iggGE64oSI6LDhyRepODp3FZ6FDIaxBVZEZCPge2gHQaHZjjLPhHsUh1IWY6g==", 

    "outing"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc792c98bf8 
    @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160625-38562-t3pccn.png>, 
    @original_filename="Beer.png", 
    @content_type="image/png", 
    @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"outing[image]\"; 
    filename=\"Beer.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, 

    "date_date(1i)"=>"2016", "date_date(2i)"=>"6", "date_date(3i)"=>"28", "date_time(1i)"=>"2016", "date_time(2i)"=>"6", "date_time(3i)"=>"26", "date_time(4i)"=>"00", "date_time(5i)"=>"47", "date_duration"=>"2", "date_title"=>"Beer Garden", "date_category"=>"Drinking", "date_description"=>"Beer Garden", "date_location"=>"New York", "date_city"=>"", "date_state"=>"", "date_zip"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create New Date"}
      User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 20]]
    Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-40htqc.png'
    Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
    Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]'
    Command :: convert '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x600" -crop "600x600+11+0" +repage '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/4331dbefbe38c7e67b6851de8064954e20160625-38562-1ljzx69'
    Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
    Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]'
    Command :: convert '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x300" -crop "300x300+5+0" +repage '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/4331dbefbe38c7e67b6851de8064954e20160625-38562-1pw6qi3'
    Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
    Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]'
    Command :: convert '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x150" -crop "150x150+2+0" +repage '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/4331dbefbe38c7e67b6851de8064954e20160625-38562-16rm0mr'
    Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
    Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]'
    Command :: convert '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-1ep7wo7.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x50" -crop "50x50+0+0" +repage '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/4331dbefbe38c7e67b6851de8064954e20160625-38562-ge9nrr'
       (0.3ms)  BEGIN
    Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/c6884357e49fd6b1fdede867c96aafb120160625-38562-we9bgq.png'
      SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "outings" ("date_title", "date_description", "date_duration", "date_category", "date_location", "date_city", "date_state", "image_file_name", "image_content_type", "image_file_size", "image_updated_at", "date_date", "date_time", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16) RETURNING "id"  [["date_title", "Beer Garden"], ["date_description", "Beer Garden"], ["date_duration", 2], ["date_category", "Drinking"], ["date_location", "New York"], ["date_city", ""], ["date_state", ""], ["image_file_name", "Beer.png"], ["image_content_type", "image/png"], ["image_file_size", 520764], ["image_updated_at", "2016-06-25 20:47:39.380829"], ["date_date", "2016-06-28"], ["date_time", "2016-06-26 00:47:00.000000"], ["user_id", 20], ["created_at", "2016-06-25 20:47:39.961401"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 20:47:39.961401"]]
    [paperclip] saving /outings/images/000/000/017/original/Beer.png
    [paperclip] saving /outings/images/000/000/017/large/Beer.png
    [paperclip] saving /outings/images/000/000/017/medium/Beer.png
    [paperclip] saving /outings/images/000/000/017/small/Beer.png
    [paperclip] saving /outings/images/000/000/017/thumb/Beer.png
       (6.4ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/outings/17
    Completed 302 Found in 2514ms (ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
```

Error Message - Unpermitted Parameter: polaroid

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-06-25 20:43:38 -0400
    Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML

      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tNW/ks6w12sLo3T8RBaZhQMBbRyddmdEh6K386BGfwoHPMeScUFCuXR/EFg/bu/hFCRXXMsNpU/Hnkj+TLGiCg==", "user"=>{"email"=>"testjun25v3@testing.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 

    "polaroid"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc78f08bf48 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/00/cvfs5p4964q5q3lq115svtf00000gn/T/RackMultipart20160625-38562-1obgcrh.png>, @original_filename="jazz.png", 
    @content_type="image/png", 
    @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[polaroid]\"; 
    filename=\"jazz.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, 

    "profile_name"=>"Jazz Man", "profile_dob"=>"", "profile_gender"=>"", "profile_zipcode"=>"", "profile_country"=>"", "profile_timezone"=>"", "profile_occupation"=>"", "profile_school"=>"", "profile_biography"=>"Jazz Lover"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}

    Unpermitted parameter: polaroid

       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'testjun25v3@testing.com' LIMIT 1
      SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "profile_name", "profile_gender", "profile_country", "profile_timezone", "profile_occupation", "profile_school", "profile_biography", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "testjun25v3@testing.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$TNIGv9c3GUh8RR.qvMv6eubGd6kgoA6aUeGichYzXWhRYF1QoFvgS"], ["profile_name", "Jazz Man"], ["profile_gender", ""], ["profile_country", ""], ["profile_timezone", ""], ["profile_occupation", ""], ["profile_school", ""], ["profile_biography", "Jazz Lover"], ["created_at", "2016-06-25 20:43:38.367890"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 20:43:38.367890"]]
       (1.1ms)  COMMIT
       (0.2ms)  BEGIN
      SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_ip" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "sign_in_count" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["last_sign_in_at", "2016-06-25 20:43:38.371506"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2016-06-25 20:43:38.371506"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "::1/128"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "::1/128"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2016-06-25 20:43:38.372369"], ["id", 20]]
       (0.3ms)  COMMIT
    Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
    Completed 302 Found in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :clubs
  has_many :outings
  has_many :events
  has_many :activities
  has_many :uploads

  has_attached_file :polaroid, styles: { large: "600x600#", medium: "300x300#", small: "150x150#", thumb: "50x50#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :polaroid, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"]
end
```

Comment: I can see that `polaroid` value is not serialised properly, how do you defined it in `user` model?

Comment: I knew I was forgetting some details!  Just added user model above.  I'm quite new to all of this, how would I serialize a value properly?

Comment: try put `multipart: true` into your form helper just like this: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#edit-and-new-views. You need that if you want to upload file via form

Comment: thanks but is form_for compatible with simple form? it looks like my code is fine with the simple_form setup, should I try the form_for instead and see how that works?

Comment: what I mean is to put `multipart: true` into html block ie `simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true })`, it should work the same regardless of standard form helper or simple_form.

Comment: ah, got it and just tried that and the other variables still save (like profile occupation) but the images do not save